# yii2 pagination dose not working Call to a member function offset() on a non-object

Tags: yii2

I am going to create yii2 pagination and I have following code but it is giving error like Call to a member function offset() on a non-object

```
 public function actionIndex() {
        $searchModel = new UsermasterSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        $dataProvider = \common\models\UsermasterSearch::find()->where(['user_id'=>1]);
        $countQuery = clone $dataProvider;
        $pages = new Pagination(['totalCount' => count($countQuery)]);
        $models = $query->offset($pages->offset)->limit($pages->limit)->all();
       return $this->render('index', ['searchModel' => $searchModel,'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,]);
    }
```

Comment: Try `['totalCount' => $countQuery->count()]`

Answer (score 0):

for  models normally create by gii and based on ModelSearch  pattern normally the pagination 
is already available by defualt complete with all the needed param

eventually you can change the page sise or configure other params

```
 public function actionIndex() {
        $searchModel = new UsermasterSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $dataProvider->query->andWhere( 'user_id  1']);

      // eventually you can change the page sise 
      $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize=5;

        return $this->render('index', ['searchModel' => $searchModel,'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,]);
    }
```

in you code there are two definition of $dataProvider  ( and i don't know if thw second is a valida dataprovider) you can avoid this simply  changing the query attribute eg: adding andWhere to the $dataProvider